# Can't restore my wordpress site from zip back up file

Tags: migration, installation

I used to have a terrible web manager, things just didn't work out. So I decided to host the thing myself. After having my website downed and kidnapped by this guy, he finally sent me a zip file that has my WordPress site.

I've been looking online and all I managed was uploading the file, and unzipping it. But it still doesn't work. The website is `http://www.arteriorismo.com/`

I get a database error. I believe this is because it was in a different hosting before or something. Can anyone give me instructions how to solve this in a step by step for super dummies?

Answer (score 2):

You need the files and a database, so here you are missing the database.

follow these steps:
http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/